What is the counterpart to "fiscal agent"?
This thread discusses the counterpart to "agent" generically. I'm looking specifically for the counterpart to "fiscal agent".
According to Investopedia:

A fiscal agent is a bank, trust company, non-profit, or other
financial entity that attends to financial and administrative issues
on behalf of another party.

When referring to the other parties served by a fiscal agent, considering the need to be specific regarding the nature of the relationship, what is the correct industry term? Is "fiscal principals" valid usage?

They're simply the client or customer of the fiscal agent. I don't think there's a more specific term for this.

Although in some cases the client would be an "investor".

No, not fiscal principal, just principal. The fiscal part isn't mutual. It's a limitation handed to the fiscal agent by the principal. And if we are being careful with words, the principal isn't a counterpart either. https://www.google.com/search?q=define+counterpart&rlz=1C1RXQR_enUS1086US1087&oq=define+counterpart&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOdIBCDU4NTZqMGo3qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

A fiscal agent isn't a formal role like being an attorney or auditor; they may perform one or more of various tasks (handle share issues, do taxes, redeem bonds, handle the payment of dividends), and there are different terms for each task. If you've more detailed questions you should ask on Money SE.

I’m voting to close this question because specialized questions about financial/tax terminology should be asked on https://money.stackexchange.com/ or https://economics.stackexchange.com/ or elsewhere.

I'm open to asking this elsewhere, but I'm not sure either of those two forums are a good fit, since this has to do with relationships between organizations, not personal finance or economics. I'd almost say it's a legal definition. Certainly these relationships have a legal aspect to them. But I don't need a term that will stand up in court, and they'll eat me alive if I try to post to Law StackExchange. I just need something I can use in a software solution that is reasonably succinct and stands a reasonable chance of being correctly understood by users.

The person or party who employs the agent to act on their behalf is sometimes called the principal. Merriam-Webster has

principal
1c : one who engages another to act as an agent subject to general control and instruction
specifically : the person from whom an agent's authority derives

